# Sharepoint Online - site closure and deletion not working

Tags: site-collection, pnp, site-deletion

We have used PnP to provision sites and add policies. But when the date for deletion has passed the site collection do not get deleted.

This is standard SharePoint functionality.. so I have no idea what's going on.

[image]

I know the images shows 1. mars, and the time job will run once a week / timezone. But I also have sites that should have been deleted aug. 2017.